# dpkg: error processing package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mongodb, dpkg

Im trying to install mongodbserver on ubuntu 14.04LTS with reference to [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#) but getting the dpkg related errors

```
root@c3:~# apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mongodb-org-server (3.0.12) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-org:
 mongodb-org depends on mongodb-org-server; however:
  Package mongodb-org-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
 mongodb-org
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i did below steps so far:

```
apt-get purge mongodb-org*
apt-get clean
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get update
```

Comment: You need to debug your post-installation script. See this answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/422264/how-to-debug-dpkg-configure-error-in-subprocess-post-installation

Comment: @Spooler: I think you answered this question :-). I took the liberty of putting that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in Spooler's comment, the important piece of information is this part:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

As part of package installation, `dpkg` will run scripts provided by the package. In this case, the package mongodb-org-server provides a script to be run after installation (called a "post-installation script", which is one of various [package maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) that a package may contain). The problem is that this script indicated a failure when it was run, by returning with an exit code of 1. The other errors are a consequence of this failure.

To solve this, you need to figure out why the post-installation script failed, usually by debugging the script. For more information on how to do this, see e.g. [How to debug dpkg configure error in subprocess post-installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422264/how-to-debug-dpkg-configure-error-in-subprocess-post-installation) on askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

It is not configured properly, try to run:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`